# Select tag in mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

in my website I have a dropdown that opens an unordered list when pressed on desktop.

On mobile and tablet I am using a select element with options, but I want to directly open the options menu from select when I press the dropdown button, I don't want to use the select element. Is this possible?

My website is [this.](http://www.pawpointer.com)

You can see the dropdown right there, and if you open it in an iPhone simulator, I want that button to open the select menu from start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, iOS Safari takes full control of select element (behavior, not the style that can be customized).

You should create the same visual effect in an other way if this behavior is really an issue for your project.

Comment: well I'm thinking about adding a trigger event, when I click on my dropdown div, it should trigger the event of click on the select element. I'll try and see:)